# Does this impeller rotating in the air produce lift

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

The red arrow represents the air movement direction, and the green arrow represents the rotation direction of the impeller, assuming that the air is not sticky.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but your rotation of the  impeller seems to be inconsistent with the direction of the air movement. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @BobD The red arrow indicates that the air blows to the rotating impeller.

Comment: Oh. Sorry. I thought the air was supposed to be the cause of the rotation

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will, due to the [Magnus Effect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_effect).

Perhaps unfortunately, though, that lift will be direct down the page with the directions you’ve drawn.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I interpret your question correctly but if the air flows around the entire object, so top as well as bottom and you manage to design the impeller properly then the answer is yes but the **lift** would be **negative**.

In this case the top would have a **lower** velocity - as the green and red velocity point into different directions - while the bottom would have **higher velocity** - as the two arrows point into the same direction. Higher velocity is connected to lower **pressure** and lower velocity to higher pressure, meaning the there will be a pressure difference and thus a force pointing downwards. This effect is termed [**Magnus effect**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_effect). If you mirror this [picture on the Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/15/Sketch_of_Magnus_effect_with_streamlines_and_turbulent_wake.svg/1920px-Sketch_of_Magnus_effect_with_streamlines_and_turbulent_wake.svg.png) you get the scenario that you sketched.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have flat blades spinning, which would centrifugally push air outwards in all directions. To create lift air movement would need to be directed downwards. Forgive me if I have misunderstood your diagram.

Comment: Note that there is also the flow of air as shown by the red arrow.

Comment: @enbinzheng Yes I see now, but either the rotation or the airflow would have to be reversed to create upwards lift, as drawn it has a downwards force from the Magnus effect.

Comment: I drew the wrong direction of rotation.